# I don't get something about q waves

Tags: heart, nerves

In the interventricular septum, there are right and left vectors, with the left vectors being the highest resultant. If the right vector is merely resistive to the left resultant, why is it that when these right vectors disappear during a branch block, the Q wave, dependent on the left resultant, now more "free", disappears in the v1 lead?
Also, why, when the left ones disappear in the vector block of the left bundle branch, does the Q wave still exist in v1, with the septum depending on the resultant which, in this case, disappears?
Edit for additional information:
Ecg of right branch block
[image]

Ecg of left branch block
[image]
Also, here's a link describing the vectors made by a normal q wave.
https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/nursing/practice/resources/cardiology/function/q_wave.php